# Как сделать два цикла одновременно в шаблоне django?

Tags: django

Имеется цикл в шаблоне

```
{% for report in reports %}
{{ report }}
{% endfor %}
```

Но также я хочу передать список, и вывести его поэлементно с каждым {{ report }}
Не могу понять, как это сделать, если у меня уже есть цикл, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: приведите какой-нибудь минимальный пример пример, того что вы хотите получить в итоге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так же как обычно пишешь один цикл внутри другого

```
{% for report in reports %}
    {% for list_item in list_in_view %}
        {{ list_item }} {{ report }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```